# How do I execute queries with multiple lines using QOCI (the Qt Oracle binding)?

Tags: oracle, qt

I am using the QOCI binding to connect Qt with an Oracle 10g database. The code is really simple:

```
QSQLQuery sqlQuery = QSQLQuery(database);
sqlquery.prepare(querystring);
sqlQuery.exec();
```

Now if querystring is only one line, it works:

```
select * from dual
```

But if it contains multiple lines, I get an ORA-911 invalid character:

```
select *
from dual
```

I have a lot of queries spanning multiple lines, so this is quite a problem. Just removing newlines in Qt is not an option, because the queries contain end-of-line comments ("--").

Any suggestions how I can execute these multi-line queries?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: The newline character was the unicode U+2029 paragraph seperator instead of a normal newline (\n). This triggered the ORA-911.

```
querystring.replace(QChar(0x2029), QChar('\n'));
```

does the trick.